# Excel-VBA: Create chart within For-loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question, whether it is possible to create chart within For-To loop function. I have below code for the calculation;

```
sub calculate_data()
dim npoint as double()
dim ncumulative as double()
dim nfactor as double()
dim npointfactor() as double
dim lastrowdata as long
dim n as long

lastrowdata = sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").end(xldown).row -2

Redim npoint(lastrowdata)
Redim ncumulative(lastrowdata)
Redim nfactor(lastrowdata)
Redim npointfactor(lastrowdata)

For n = 1 To lastrowdata
npoint(n) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2 + n, 2)
ncumulative(n) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2 + n, 3)
nfactor(n) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2 + n, 4)

npointfactor(n) = npoint(n) / nfactor(n)
next n

for n = 1 To lastrowdata
Sheets("Sheet1").cells(2 + n, 5) = npointfactor(n)
next n

end sub
```

Then, i would like to have chart by plotting the npointfactor(n) as y-axis and ncumulative(n) as x-axis. Is there any way to get this?

Comment: I'm not  sure if you could set the values directly as sourcedata but you could certainly write them to a new sheet then create a chart with the data range as source

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping, just put a formula in the worksheet. Then make your chart:

```
Sub Calc_Data_2()
  Dim sht1 As Worksheet
  Dim LastRowData As Long
  Dim rChartX As Range, rChartY As Range

  Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' or ActiveSheet
  LastRowData = sht1.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row - 2

  Set rChartX = sht1.Range("C3").Resize(LastRowData)
  Set rChartY = sht1.Range("E3").Resize(LastRowData)

  rChartY.Formula = "=B3/D3"

  'With sht1.Shapes.AddChart.Chart ' Excel 2007-2010
  With sht1.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart ' Excel 2013-2016
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .SetSourceData Union(rChartX, rChartY)
  End With
End Sub
```